# Prefix "dis" in words

Tags: prefixes

As much as I know the prefix **dis** mostly means - **no**, **stop**, and **the opposite**.

In such words like: **dislike** - stop liking, **disrespect** - no respect, **disconnect** - the opposite for connect.

But in such words like: **discover**, **discuss**, **disguise**, **display** what does **"dis"** mean? Or maybe it isn't a prefix in these words?

Comment: "dis" is not always a prefix.  If it was, "discuss" would mean "not swear", "display" would mean "work".  and "disgust" would mean "no wind".  :-)

Comment: I can answer for **discover**: it also means **opposite** in the sense of **uncovering** an idea that was previously **covered** in the figurative sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I am inclined to agree with fixer1234's comment, having done a bit of research on all the words you mention it seems that *all* of them lead back to origins with dis/des prefixes. It's just some of these words have taken a few detours in definition which don't make that connection as clear as some of the words you mentioned earlier.

For [*discover*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=discover), the word originates from the Late latin *discooperire*, which breaks down into *dis* (opposite of) and *cooperire* (to cover up), as Trent mentions in his comment above.

For [*discuss*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=discussion), the word originates from the Latin *discutere*, which breaks down into *dis* (apart) and *quatere* (to shake). It seems that the definition shifted from smashing apart to scatter or disperse, then to investigate or examine and finally to debate.

For [*disguise*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=disguise), the word originates from the Old French *desguiser*, which breaks down into *des* (away, off) and *guise* (style, appearance - a word we still use today).

For [*display*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=display), the word originates from the Latin *displicare*, which breaks down into *dis* (apart) and *plicare* (to fold). This definition was used with regards to sails and flags (the idea of unfurling them/revealing them) and has gradually morphed to what it is today.

Comment: I would just like to add that searching for "[word] etymology" in your preferred search engine is a really good way to start delving into the origins of words, and how they've morphed and changed over time to mean what they do now.

Comment: An even better way is to consult the Oxford English Dictionary,  though it isn't free online. Now and then you can find on eBay the miniaturized  compact edition of the dictionary, for which you will need a magnifying glass, unless you have eagle eyes. http://public.oed.com/page-tags/etymology/

Answer (score 1):

[image: Compact Edition of the Oxford English Dictionary]

The miniaturized "compact edition" of the dictionary, with magnifying glass.